# error when I use GWT RPC

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, asynccallback

I have a problem with Eclipse when I use an RPC..
If I use a single method call it's all in the right direction but if I add a new method to handle the server I get the following error:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null): null
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeBoolean(ModuleSpace.java:184)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeBoolean(JavaScriptHost.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RpcStatsContext.isStatsAvailable(RpcStatsContext.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:221)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Can I have more services in an asynchronous call right? Where am I wrong?

This is my implementation MyService:

```
package de.vogella.gwt.helloworld.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;

public interface MyService extends RemoteService {
    //chiamo i metodi presenti sul server

    public void creaXML(String nickname,String pass,String email2,String gio,String mes, String ann);

    public void setWeb(String userCorrect,String query, String titolo,String snippet,String url);
}
```

MyServiceAsync

```
package de.vogella.gwt.helloworld.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface MyServiceAsync {

    void creaXML(String nickname,String pass,String email2,String gio,String mes, String ann,AsyncCallback<Void> callback);

    void setWeb(String userCorrect,String query, String titolo,String snippet,String url, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
}
```

RPCService:

```
package de.vogella.gwt.helloworld.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.ServiceDefTarget;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;

public class RPCService implements MyServiceAsync {
     MyServiceAsync service = (MyServiceAsync) GWT.create(MyService.class);
     ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) service;


        public RPCService()
        {
            endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "rpc");

        }


        public void creaXML(String nickname,String pass,String email2,String gio,String mes, String ann,AsyncCallback callback)
        {
            service.creaXML(nickname, pass, email2, gio, mes, ann, callback);
        }

        public void setWeb(String userCorrect,String query, String titolo,String snippet,String url,AsyncCallback callback) {

            service.setWeb(userCorrect,query, titolo,snippet,url,callback);

        }
}
```

MyServiceImpl

```
package de.vogella.gwt.helloworld.server;

import java.io.*;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import de.vogella.gwt.helloworld.client.MyService;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.NodeList;

public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyService {
    //metodo che inserisce il nuovo iscritto
    public void creaXML(String nickname,String pass,String email2,String gio,String mes, String ann){
        .......
    }

    public void setWeb(String userCorrect,String query, String titolo,String snippet,String url) {
        .....
    }
```

In the app in client-side I do

```
RPCService rpc2 = New RPCService()
rpc2.setWeb(..,...,...,...,callback);
```

and

```
RPCService rpc = New RPCService()
rpc.creaXML(..,...,...,...,callback); (in other posizions in the code...)
```

and..

```
AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback()
{
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
    {
        Window.alert("Failure!");
    }

    public void onSuccess(Object result)
    {

        Window.alert("Successoooooo");


    }
};
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <!-- Servlets -->

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>De_vogella_gwt_helloworld.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>rPCImpl</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>de.vogella.gwt.helloworld.server.MyServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>rPCImpl</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/de_vogella_gwt_helloworld/rpc</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Thank you all for your attention

Sebe

Comment: Please correct the code formatting and make sure the code compiles. In RPCService class you have the following code in the body of the class: `MyServiceAsync service = (MyServiceAsync) GWT.create(MyService.class); ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget)`. Shouldn't it be in the constructor?

Comment: If I insert MyServiceAsync service = (MyServiceAsync) GWT.create(MyService.class); ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) service, in the constructor, raise an errpr in the methods to implement :(

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be invoking your RPC services in a strange way.

There is a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) in GWT web page showing how this should be done.

**EDIT:**

[This bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4409) reported in GWT bugs database may be related to your problem (the stack trace is very similar). Some information about the bug can be also found [here](http://joannaandjohn.blogspot.com/2010/01/gwt-comgooglegwtcoreclientjavascriptexc.html).

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Tutorials~RPC_To_Java  If I use only one method (creaXMl or setWeb)It works, but does not work if I use them both ..
What can it be? Thanks for the reply

Comment: I understand what's the problem.
The error resulted when the call to launch an operation of a click in a FlexTable.
This is because if the method to launch any other part, it work fine.

How can I solve this? I use to force the table ....:(

Comment: I have been looking in GWT bugs database for information about your stack trace and surprisingly I found [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4409). It may be your problem. Take a look at it (some possible solutions are suggested in the comments of the bug - maybe some of them will help you).

Answer (score 1):

I lost my pass and I recreate the account... I see your board..it's a problem with my browser web... If I use Internet Explorer it work fine, but If I use Firefox (my predefinite browser) throw the exception (but It compile fine). I have not found anything that I can fix it...

Comment: Have you looked at [the GWT bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4409) I mentioned in my answer? The bug was reported to exist when you run application in Firefox (as it happens in your case). [Some people](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4409#c14) suggest that clearing Firefox history helps, [some other](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4409#c2) suggest removing `<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6">` line from gwt.xml file (if the line exists in the file).